# Weighted Average of Multi Class AUC

Tags: python, tensorflow, auc

Here, I can calculate the AUC score of each class individually in a multiclass problem (not to be confused with multilabel.)

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MulticlassAUC(tf.keras.metrics.AUC):
    """AUC for a single class in a muliticlass problem.

    Parameters
    ----------
    pos_label : int
        Label of the positive class (the one whose AUC is being computed).

    from_logits : bool, optional (default: False)
        If True, assume predictions are not standardized to be between 0 and 1.
        In this case, predictions will be squeezed into probabilities using the
        softmax function.

    sparse : bool, optional (default: True)
        If True, ground truth labels should be encoded as integer indices in the
        range [0, n_classes-1]. Otherwise, ground truth labels should be one-hot
        encoded indicator vectors (with a 1 in the true label position and 0
        elsewhere).

    **kwargs : keyword arguments
        Keyword arguments for tf.keras.metrics.AUC.__init__(). For example, the
        curve type (curve='ROC' or curve='PR').
    """

    def __init__(self, pos_label, from_logits=False, sparse=True, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.pos_label = pos_label
        self.from_logits = from_logits
        self.sparse = sparse

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
        """Accumulates confusion matrix statistics.

        Parameters
        ----------
        y_true : tf.Tensor
            The ground truth values. Either an integer tensor of shape
            (n_examples,) (if sparse=True) or a one-hot tensor of shape
            (n_examples, n_classes) (if sparse=False).

        y_pred : tf.Tensor
            The predicted values, a tensor of shape (n_examples, n_classes).

        **kwargs : keyword arguments
            Extra keyword arguments for tf.keras.metrics.AUC.update_state
            (e.g., sample_weight).
        """
        if self.sparse:
            y_true = tf.math.equal(y_true, self.pos_label)
            y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true)
        else:
            y_true = y_true[..., self.pos_label]

        if self.from_logits:
            y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
        y_pred = y_pred[..., self.pos_label]

        super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs)

    def result(self):
        """Computes the AUC score."""
        return super().result()
```

Example usage:

```
model.compile(..., metrics=[MulticlassAUC(0),MulticlassAUC(1),MulticlassAUC(2)])
```

Which works as expected and outputs the AUC score of each class separately:

```
196/196 [==============================] - 20s 91ms/step - loss: 2.1288 - multiclass_auc: 0.7664 - multiclass_auc_1: 0.6847 -  - multiclass_auc_2: 0.7847 - val_loss: 1.9751 - val_multiclass_auc: 0.8332 - val_multiclass_auc_1: 0.8227 - val_multiclass_auc_2: 0.7227
```

However, I want to calculate a weighted average (with optional weights as input) of all the classes in my custom AUC. To be more precise, for the above output, the calculated val_auc for each class is 0.8332, 0.8227, 0.7227. Now let's say we want to calculate the weighted average of them with the weights of (1, 1, 3). Then the result would be:

```
(0.8332, 0.8227, 0.7227) * (1, 1, 3) / (1+1+3)
```

But I have no clue how can I do this in a single class. Can anyone help with this issue?